# External identity provider

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

Im using duende identity server 4
and I have a requirement to create a login with facebook and google so first I setup my project and user the quickstart of duende software and i wast able to realize the requirement but i pretend that when i login with facebook or google or whatever external provider it will be stored on the table IdentityProviders

[image]

but the table is empty despite the table AspNetUserLogins has this content

[image]

Comment: We don't post images of technical information like sample data or results. It's the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored. Instead, edit the question to use _formatted text_.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue... but in the documentation https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/upgrades/is4_v4_to_dis_v6/ this table is added for IdentityServer v6

https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/pull/188

Answer (score 0):

The IdentityProviders table is used by the "Dynamic Providers" feature which is available in the Enterprise license only. IdentityServer only reads that table, it's up to you to populate the table. The contents of the table is one line for each of the external identity providers added. The typical use is for per-customer Saml2 or OpenID connect providers for a multi-tenanted SAAS application.

AspNetUserLogins table contains the external user id for each user.

Everything looks correct in your example. It looks like you are adding GitHub and Google as providers in your service setup by calling AddGitHub() and AddGoogle() on your AuthenticationBuilder.